# Android LinearLayout Alignment Issue

Tags: android, alignment, android-linearlayout

This is currently what I have.

[image: http://i2.photobucket.com/albums/y2/Lokolo/linearLayout.png]

All the boxes are linear layouts. But I want the Star to be right aligned. I have added a TextView with "   " just to make a little space but I will be removing this. If I change the TextView to fill_parent it causes the Star to go off to the right of the screen (as expected but I was hoping it would fill up everything inbetween itself and the star)

I can't think how to make the ImageView go to the right. The layout_grvaity is currently right but this hasn't changed anything.

Not very good with design ;)

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better way is to use a `relative layout` and then set `android:alignParentRight="true"`, otherwise you can try setting width of your view as `fill_parent` and then set `gravity` to "right".

Hope this helps!!

Comment: Thanks I used the relative layout instead of the linear, and right aligned the star to the textview and it worked. Thanks! (sorry can't up your answer because I req 15 rep!)

Comment: No prob buddy.. I personally always prefer relative layout over Linear layout. It has got so much features for creating a layout.

Answer (score 0):

A solution is to set the layout width to wrap content for your `TextView` and its gravity to 1.0. It will take all the unused space and thus push your star on the right without making it go off.